# How make jda bot respond random embed messages on slash command?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am working on a bot in Java (JDA) and currently I am working on slash command called slap - I guess it’s well known plug-in. User types /slap @mentionUser and as a reply bot sends embed with text “user slapped user” and some anime gif. I wish for my bot to choose randomly different embeds created by me each time someone use the command. Any ideas? I guess I could do it with Random class, but I am new in Java and wish to get some help with that.

I just made bot responding with embed, but still didn’t figure it out how to get random embeds.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.